# "Mobile" vs. "cellphone" in AE

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, british-english, word-usage

I already heard Americans use the term "mobile" for "cellphone" -- which I thought was chiefly BE -- and so I wish you could tell if such usage of "mobile" has any currency in GAE?

Unless it might be called a "mobile" by Americans outside of the US or frequently traveling to Europe.

Comment: I find it astonishing that this most modern of conveniences, born into a globalised world, does not have a universal name. In the UK it is a mobile, in America a cell-phone, in France 'un portable', and in Malaysia they call it a 'hand-phone'.

Comment: Anecdotally in California (San Francisco) I hear 'mobile phone' being used more than 'cell phone'. However this could be biased - as a British English speaker the Americans I speak with may be adjusting their language to me.

Comment: What is GAE? Google App Engine? Greater American English? Typo for AmE?

Comment: @1006a probably General American English https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_American

Comment: My experience is hardly anyone uses "mobile" or "cell" anymore. It's just a "phone". If you mean a landline phone, you would call it a "landline" or, in an office, a "desk phone".

Comment: @nohat That makes sense, thanks. With acronyms, google is not so much my friend--too many possibilities! And it makes a difference here, since I think for Google App Engine (top suggestion, of course) *mobile* probably **is** more common than *cell* or *cellular*.

Comment: My take is that *mobile* is gaining currency mainly as an adjective, not as a noun—I don't really hear people say *where's my mobile?* (unless they mean a bobbing baby entertainment thing) but I do hear *that's my mobile number* at rates that might approach *that's my cell number*, and phrases like *mobile devices* and *mobile app* are pretty standard (though these come up in casual conversation far less often than just a *phone*).

Comment: @WS2 and in Germany for quite some time it was called a "handy"

Comment: In Germany we call it a 'Handy'

Comment: @WS2 French and English and German are different languages. Thank goodness they are different. It is just a phone, yes, unless one needs to make the distinction for some practical reason.//I much prefer anecdotal experiences from well-informed participants or participants with broad experience to googled hits with no critical input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In common AE conversation you would say "cellphone" or just "phone".  Mobile or mobile phone is recognized and used in marketing.

> Usage:  "Where the hell did I leave my (cell) phone."

Comment: “Mobile” is also used in a lot of address book apps. These days, I hear _phone, cell,_ and _mobile,_ roughly in that order. I mostly use _phone,_ sometimes _mobile._

Comment: @BraddSzonye - I agree on the order.  It is all contextual but phone pretty much means mobile now.  If you are referring to a non-mobile you have to add description for that - landline or home phone.  I do hear mobile used a lot in France but if hear someone in America saying mobile, I think they are a Brit or a tech-wannabe.

Comment: I agree.  It's rarely used in plain conversation.  I've never taken a sip of tea and said, "Ring me on my mobile."

Answer (score 2):

Mobile or cell phone can be used in America and both are used, but yes cell is used more often in everyday conversation.  But on TV commercial and radio commercials here in America the term mobile phone is probably used a little more often.